# Parse target targetNamespace and name from a wsdl url

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am consuming a webservices url.I have a WSDL url.Now i want to parse WSDL url to obtain the targetNamespace and name attributes of the wsdl.

The url i have is : http://webservices.company.com:9080/WS/WebService?wsdl.

can i access the wsdl from this location to obtain the targetNamespace and name from it using java? All i want is targetNamespace and name from the wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is possible. 
I'd recommend WSDL4J for this.